# Sitefinity 6.0 Upgrade

Tags: telerik, sitefinity

Currently my sitefinity is working on Version 5.4.

I have to upgrade sitefinity to version 6.3.
I have followed all the steps mentioned in the sitefinity forum. First I upgraded to 6.0 and it worked fine. One small change I did manually was that I had to add a block of code mentioned below to force assembly redirect since even after upgrading, my site was referencing to the older version(5.4.4010.0)

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.4.4010.0" newVersion="6.0.4210.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity.Model" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.4.4010.0" newVersion="6.0.4210.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

After I updated the above block in my web.config file, the application worked absolutely fine.

Now, as instructed I tried to upgrade to version 6.1 from version 6.0 following the procedures mentioned on the stefinity forum.
After up-gradation I had to modify the the web.config with the code mentioned below:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.4.4010.0" newVersion="6.2.4900.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity.Model" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.4.4010.0" newVersion="6.2.4900.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.0.4210.0" newVersion="6.2.4900.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity.Model" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.0.4210.0" newVersion="6.2.4900.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

After this modification, the application works fine however, the product description page does not seem to work. It gives me an error mentioned below.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item
 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
 
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item
 
Source Error: 
 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
 
Stack Trace: 
 
 
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item]
   Telerik.Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Utility.Guard.ArgumentNotNull(Object argumentValue, String argumentName) +68
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Lifecycle.LifecycleDecorator.GetMaster(ILifecycleDataItemGeneric item) +67
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Lifecycle.LifecycleDecorator.Telerik.Sitefinity.Lifecycle.ILifecycleDecorator.GetMaster(ILifecycleDataItem cnt) +61
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Ecommerce.Orders.Implementations.ProductOptionsPopulator.GetProductVariation(Product product, List`1 selectedAttributeValues) +192
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Ecommerce.Catalog.Web.UI.ProductOptionsControl.GetSelectedOptions() +1255
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Ecommerce.Catalog.Web.UI.ProductOptionsControl.get_SelectedOptions() +38
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Ecommerce.Orders.Web.UI.AddToCartWidget.GetOptionDetails() +322
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Ecommerce.Orders.Web.UI.AddToCartWidget.GetProductVariation() +39
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Ecommerce.Orders.Web.UI.AddToCartWidget.SwitchVisibilityBasedOnInventory() +45
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Ecommerce.Orders.Web.UI.AddToCartWidget.InitializeControls(GenericContainer container) +45
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.SimpleView.CreateChildControls() +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
 
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408
```

This is my upgrade trace

```
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 3/5/2014 6:29:03 AM

Message: PASSED : SiteInitializer: Upgrade to 4100 (method: ReorderAdminMenu_6_0)


----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 3/5/2014 6:29:05 AM

Message: PASSED : SiteInitializer: Upgrade to 4100 (method: AddContentLocationsBackendPage)


----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 3/5/2014 6:29:05 AM

Message: PASSED : SiteInitializer: Upgrade to 4200 (method: UpgradeBackendTemplatesRemoveIE8Compatibility)


----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 3/5/2014 6:30:19 AM

Message: Libraries: Upload mode changed to Silverlight


----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 3/5/2014 6:30:38 AM

Message: PASSED : Copy data from sf_ec_product_type.title to sf_ec_product_type.title_


----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 3/5/2014 6:30:38 AM

Message: PASSED : Copy data from sf_ec_product_type.title_plural to sf_ec_product_type.title_plural_


----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 3/5/2014 6:32:09 AM

Message: PASSED : Scheduling task for updating content locations


----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 3/5/2014 6:35:03 AM

Message: PASSED : Updating content locations service


----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 3/5/2014 6:53:28 AM

Message: PASSED : SiteInitializer: Upgrade to 4300 (method: Upgrade_InitializeNavigationWidgetTemplates)


----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 3/5/2014 6:53:44 AM

Message: PASSED: OpenAccessLibrariesProvider - Prepare 'sf_media_thumbnails' table for upgrade


----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 3/5/2014 6:54:20 AM

Message: PASSED WITH WARNINGS: OpenAccessLibrariesProvider: Prepare thumbnails legacy mode: Telerik.OpenAccess.OpenAccessException: SQL exception on 'update sf_media_thumbnails set total_size=DATALENGTH(dta) where dta is not null' : Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding..For more details see the error log


----------------------------------------
```

Can anyone help me out this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a tool like Beyond Compare to compare your site files with the vanilla Sitefinity version you're trying to upgrade to. In the folder where you ran the Sitefinity.exe  file from the Sitefinity project manager to do the upgrade, there should be a another folder called _EmptyProject. Compare that with your site and make sure all the correct dll's were moved over and that the web.config was updated appropriately.